# Ошибка в инструкции CREATE DATABASE (C#, TSQL)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server, исключения

Нужно создать БД через код, после чего подключиться к ней (насколько я знаю, подключение - это инструкция USE) и после этого выполнить скрипт с созданием таблиц, процедур и т. п.
При таком вроде бы простом коде вылетает исключение: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DATABASE'.
Что не так? Кажется, проще уж некуда.

```cs
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0}; Integrated Security=SSPI;", @"(localdb)\Projects"));
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlCommand.CommandText = String.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0}; USE DATABASE {0};", "testdb");
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: _"Нужно создать БД через код"_ -- см. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у вас неверная запись последовательности команд,
для начала необходимо выполнить команду

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb
```

и только после создания базы выполнить следующую команду

```
USE testdb
```

Маленький совет, перед тем как выполнять **SQL** код из под **C#**, попробуйте его погонять в **SQL Management Studio**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Изменил, разделил команду (create, выполнить, use, выполнить) - база создается, но почему-то вылетает та же ошибка.
Извините за наверняка глупый вопрос, но где найти SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @Max http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/MgmtStudio%2064BIT/SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe

Comment: @Max Какая ошибка вылетает? вы точно выполнили вторую команду как я написал? без слова `DATABASE`

Comment: _"где найти SQL Management Studio"_ -- не обязательно, т.к. есть [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt204009.aspx) встраиваемый в VS.

Comment: @Stack необязательно, но желательно, встроенные в студию средства крайне урезаны по функционалу

Comment: _"встроенные в студию средства крайне урезаны по функционалу"_ -- а что, из необходимого, отсутствует в SSDT?

Comment: @Stack как визуально в дереве посмотреть ключи?

Comment: @Stack и *желательно* не равно *необязательно*

Comment: @Dmitry _"как визуально в дереве посмотреть ключи?"_ -- в SQL Server Object Explorer можно выбрать базу данных, затем Tables - таблица - Keys выводятся ключи. Также ключи видны в View Designer. или это не то, что надо?

Comment: @Stack зачем мне открывать дизайнер таблицы когда я хочу просто увидеть ключи и индексы, а еще хочу просто поглядеть типы столбцов. Думаю не стоит сравнивать мерседес с запорожцем в рамках SO

Comment: @Dmitry _"зачем мне открывать дизайнер таблицы когда я хочу просто увидеть ключи и индексы"_ -- а кто говорит, что надо открывать дизайнер? в дизайнере они _также_ видны, как и в дереве в SQL Server Object Explorer, где они отображаются точно также как и в SQL Server Management Studio - Object Explorer.

Comment: @Stack у меня в 2015 студии этого не видно, и сколько я помню их никогда и не было видно. На этом считаю дискуссию закрытой

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33955/discussion-between-stack-and-dmitry).

Comment: @Dmitry _"у меня в 2015 студии этого не видно, и сколько я помню их никогда и не было видно"_ -- понятно. но все меняется. надо поставить update. сравните [скриншоты](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26658162#26658162)

Comment: @Dmitry, прошу прощения, действительно невнимательно прочитал. Спасибо большое, работает.